# SQL conditional update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**I have:**
Table with columns A int, B int, C int

**I need to build query like**:

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    A -= B -- and then if A < 0 do A = C
```

Is it possible to do without cursor? If it is useful, I use MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you're looking for

```
UPDATE
    Table
SET
    A = CASE 
           WHEN (A - B) < 0 THEN
             C
           ELSE 
               (A - B)
         END
```